# Поток с использованием подключения к серверу

Tags: android, java, сокет

Решил изучать java и создание Android приложений на ней.
Итак, Reg активити со всякими условиями:

```
     public class Reg extends Activity{
     TextView InfoText;
     Button Reg;
     Button Cancel;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.lregistration);
            InfoText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.InfoText);//Информирующий
 текст
            Reg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reg);//Кнопка
 регистрации
            Cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Cancel);//Назад
         OnClickListener Click = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId())
                {
                case R.id.reg:
                /*Код при нажатии кнопки Регистрация*/
     /*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
     `
```

**CONservice.getCon();**

```
        InfoText.setText("olol");
     /*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
                break;
                case R.id.Cancel:
                    /*Код при нажатии кнопки Назад*/
                    break;
            }}};
            Reg.setOnClickListener(Click);
        };
     };
```

Файл коннектер: CONservice.java:

```
package service;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.io.*;
public class CONservice {
    static AffableThread mSecondThread;
 public static void main(String[] args)  {
    getCon();
}
 public static void getCon(){
     mSecondThread = new AffableThread();
     mSecondThread.start();
}
}
class AffableThread extends Thread
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {    
        try{ 
            Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5555);
            }catch(UnknownHostException e){}catch(IOException e){}
    }  
}
```

То есть имеется некий экран с кнопкой, и при нажатии на нее должна быть совершена попытка подключения к серверу и вывести мне на экран текст "olol".
Сервер запущен и ждет подключений, запускаем приложение через эмуль, нажимаем кнопку - и вуаля - никакого соединения нет, никаких ошибок нет и лишь только смутная надпись olol.
Вроде как не экстрасенс гадать, что там в багажнике. Помогите, люди добрые))

Comment: РАзрешение на использование Интернет добавили?

Comment: @metalurgus в манифесте добавил ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE, INTERNET. Все равно то же самое

Comment: так, подождите, вы пытаетесь подключиться на 127.0.0.1:5555, то есть к порту 5555 самого эмулятора. А вы что либо слушаете на этом же эмуляторе на этом порту? Ему есть куда подключаться?

Comment: @metalurgus Запущен локальный сервер с портом 5555. В нем при подключении выводит в консоль - Client!. Сервер работает, ожидает подключений, проверен.

Comment: @VladEv1L, где запущен локальный сервер? на компе, или на эмуляторе Android?

Comment: кроме того, среди 65536 портов вы выбрали почему-то 5555, который как раз занят самим эмулятором

Comment: @metalurgus Сервер запущен отдельно от проекта через консоль на ПК. 
Пытаюсь подключиться к нему через эмулятор. 
Поменял порты на 27018 - исход тот же.

Comment: @Виталина ♦ Хорошо, поставлю как верный, но вроде бы запустил на реальном устройстве, указав IP моего ПК, на котором запущен сервер - ошибку в приложении выдало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эмулятор, так же, как и любое устройство с поддержкой сети, выступает для себя localhost'ом и имеет адресс 127.0.0.1. Вы же запускаете сервер на компе. Подумайте логически. Эмулятор - это виртуальная машина. Что будет, если на виртуальную машину установить, например, винду, и запросить на ней адресс 127.0.0.1? Неужели вы думаете, что она будет стучаться на хостовую ОС? Нет, она будет запрашивать свой собственный IP. Так же само и эмулятор Android.

Comment: Пошаманил, в итоге добился чего хотел, все заработало